Understanding [person]+相手に
I encountered two examples of [person]+相手に:

Boruto Blue Vortex ch. 11:



She is Beautiful ch. 42:


I wonder how [person]+相手に is grammatically understood. Is it [person]の相手に or [person]を相手に(して)? I think the latter makes sense and I want a confirmation.

There are two ways of interpreting this.

相手 can work as a suffix that forms a no-adjective, so you can think this is simply an adverbial form of 清香相手の. See: How is 「相手」being used here?
Alternatively, you can think this is short for 清香を相手に. See:  How to parse 「Nを相手に、」 But note that you cannot always omit this を at this position. Whether you can omit を in AをBに depends on B.

清香の相手 only refers to "Sayaka's partner/opponent".
